# mod_rewrite / htaccess error after rewriting url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a website which I am trying to implement url rewriting for tidy looking urls...the problem I am having is that when a visitor goes from my index page to the venues page, when they try to come back to the home page I get a 404 error.

My link looks like this:

```
<a href='venues/a-venue'>A VENUE</a>
```

My rewrite looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^venues/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ venues.php?venue=$1 [L]
```

This works absolutely fine, and loads all the necessary JS/CSS/image files etc - but when the user then clicks on the logo at the top of the page which has the link:

```
<a href='index.php'><img src='images/logo.png'></a>
```

The page cannot be displayed because it's looking for an index page in venues/a-venue (I presume). I have tried loads to get it to work but am at my wits end and cannot find a thread anywhere which helps with this specific problem.

Any advice? I am very new to .htaccess files and mod_rewrite so please be gentle with me

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
<a href='/'><img src='images/logo.png'></a>
```

Comment: That's taken me to the index page of my servers "htdocs" folder?

Comment: Yes.. thats what you wanted right.The index page is the home page or it isnt?

Comment: It is but that's taking me up a level to the folder above

Comment: its not taking you away from the folder. YOu have the venues.php and the index.php in the same folder.. the url rewrite that you have written only shows in the url bar as if it is taking you to another folder,.. like **venues/a-vernue** .. Its just for display.. There are no such folders on your website. the only job of that url according to your rewrite rule is that if someone calls a webpage from venues/a-venue it will pass the value of a-venue in get request to the venues.php file.. I hope you understand.. I mean there are no folders at all..Hope that helps

Comment: When I hover over the logo it's telling me that the link goes to "localhost" instead of "localhost/mysite" - I apologise if I am not explaining myself very well. The index.php and venues.php are in the "mysite" folder inside htdocs.

Comment: Okay i get it now.. You have your folder like this..

 htdocs/mysite/index.php 

and it is taking you to the index.php from htdocs instead of mysite

Just say yes if this is right

Comment: this means that your .htaccess file which stores your url rules is probably stored in the htdocs folder. or you have 2 .htaccess files, one in the mysite folder and one in the htdocs folder which is causing the problem.
You shd remove the .htaccess file from the htdocs folder.

Comment: There is no .htaccess file in the htdocs folder, I only have the one file in the mysite folder

Comment: I gotta tell you that you will bump into some issues if u ever plan to put this website in productions.

I personally suggest you rather request you to not make a seperate folder in the htdocs. but use your htdocs as your parent directoy.
if you do so you need not make changes. but if you still want to have files inside that directory

Just add this line to 
RewriteRule ^home?$ index.php 

to your htaccess file and change the a link to this

<a href='/home'><img src='images/logo.png'></a>

And i deserve and upvote .

Comment: Still don't work mate, does exactly the same thing. I won't waste any more of your time and will keep at it myself. I have loads of sites on my test server so they need to be in separate folders

Comment: just add virtual servers in your apache.. Believe me it will save hours of time later..I have  20 test sites.. thats what i do.. just read about it. its damn easy.

Comment: I have read loads about it but as I said - am new to it. I don't understand virtual servers so will do exactly that